# How to log an error with Swiftlog package?

Tags: swift

When I am catching a error and want to log it with the official swift logger `swiftlog` package like this:

```
do {
     try something()
} catch {
     logger.error(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

I get the message `"Cannot conversation value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Logger.Message'`
I get a similar message for `logger.error(error)`.

How to do this best?

[image: the problem]

Comment: Have you tried using `"\(error)"`?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't look elegant

Comment: How is that relevant to your question?

Comment: :-) I was wondering about the best way to do this. I think it is cumbersome to always use String interpolation. I was actually wondering whether I overlooked a part of swiftlog API as I thought logging an error should be standard.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and also wondered why there is no default option to log an error directly.

Anyway, to make it a more convenient i wrote an extension to `Logger` to handle an error.

```swift
extension Logger {
    func error(_ error: Error) {
        self.error("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```